# Faster alternative to compute convolution in the frequency domain in torch

Tags: performance, profiling, fft, pytorch, convolution

I'm implementing a custom convolution in `torch`, which converts an image to the frequency domain using `FFT`, computes the product between kernel and image and then computes the inverse `FFT`. Although it works, I've noticed that the product computation is rather slow. Is there a way to optimize it?

I've added a `timer` to everything to see how it goes and got the following results (testing on `cpu`):

```
squeezes - done in 4.17232513E-05s
real - done in 1.67846680E-04s
im - done in 7.53402710E-05s
stack - done in 8.36849213E-05s
sum - done in 3.96490097E-04s
bias - done in 1.64508820E-05s
```

Here is my implementation:

*Note that I'm not computing the `FFT` and its inverse in here. The `torch`implementation of these operations are rather fast.*

```
def fconv2d(input, kernel, bias=None):
    # Computes the convolution in the frequency domain given
    # an input of shape (B, Cin, H, W) and kernel of shape (Cout, Cin, H, W).
    # Expects input and kernel already in frequency domain!

    with timer('squeezes'):
        kernel = kernel.unsqueeze(0)
        # Expand kernel to (B, Cout, Cin, H, W)
        # Expand input to (B, Cout, Cin, H, W)
        input = input.unsqueeze(1)
    # Compute the multiplication
    # (a+bj)*(c+dj) = (ac-bd)+(ad+bc)j
    with timer('real'):
        real = input[..., 0] * kernel[..., 0] - \
               input[..., 1] * kernel[..., 1]
    with timer('im'):
        im = input[..., 0] * kernel[..., 1] + \
             input[..., 1] * kernel[..., 0]
    # Stack both channels and sum-reduce the input channels dimension
    with timer('stack'):
        out = torch.stack([real, im], -1)

    with timer('sum'):
        out = out.sum(dim=-4)
    # Add bias
    with timer('bias'):
        if bias is not None:
            bias = bias.expand(1, 1, 1, bias.shape[0]).permute(0, 3, 1, 2)
            out += bias
    return out
```

Comment: I cannot imagine this multiplication being slower than one FFT (which you need to apply 2x forward and 1x back). Your bottleneck should be there. If the convolution kernel is small, as is usually the case in CCNs, a spatial-domain convolution is a lot faster than a FFT-based convolution.

Comment: Have you tried converting `input` and `kernel` to complex-valued matrices and use [`numpy.multiply`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html) instead of a custom coded complex multiplication?

Comment: Your complex multiplication creates lots of intermediate arrays. You can use [`torch.einsum`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.einsum) to avoid the intermediate array before summing. I would imagine once you have larger arrays this cost diminishes.

Comment: @Coolness, I thought about that but I did not manage to do it using `einsum`. Although, I've read about it a couple of times I have never used, so I don't have any experience with it. Can you help me derive the `einsum`expression?

Comment: @Coolness ohh, I guess you mean to use  `einsum` before real and im summation? Like `real = torch.einsum('bihw,bohw->bohw', input[..., 0], kernel[..., 0]) - torch.einsum('bihw,bohw->bohw', input[..., 1], kernel[..., 1])`?
So the summation of `in_channels` occurs in place at every multiplication instead of carrying the `in_channels` until the very end?

Comment: @Eduardo yeah that's right. It should help at least with memory usage, for large tensors.

Comment: For memory yes, but I've verified that it is much slower (about 3x on cpu and much more on gpu). Thanks anyway